# How to install Postfix in an all default way (no setup wizard) and to be used with no email DNS records?

Tags: debian, dns, postfix, smtp

The following question is a follow up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499776/transferring-contact-form-inputs-to-my-email-account-without-emailing-dns-record).

In a latest Debian 9 stable I desire to install Postfix to send email from my machine to my very own Gmail account by the quickest install possible; no Postfix setup wizard and no pre/post installation configuring of email DNS records.

One could say that then the emails, **if will be sent at all**, will go to the spam dir but it doesn't matter to me as then I'll put the machine's IP on a goodlist.

How to install Postfix in an all default way (no setup wizard) and to be used with no email DNS records?

Comment: Postfix is an MTA, and mail uses DNS records (at least, to get to your Gmail account, it would).

Comment: @JeffSchaller and what if I don't use DNS records, nothing will get even to the spam dir? If so, it's so sad to me...

Comment: A default installation of postfix on Debian and an mx record in DNS should be fine for sending and receiving mail.  However, most receiving servers will place your sent mail in spam or maybe even reject it outright...  Also, a default installation on Debian is rather insecure.  Your mail server will likely be compromised and very likely be spoofed... So, to prevent spoofing, you will need to add a DMARC record in DNS... without the DMARC record... your **domain** will probably be marked as a malicious domain and Google may block... or your domain will be blacklisted because of spoofing.

Comment: @Christopher ... In the last few years a lot has changed with email servers.  For example, there is now a requirement, [instituted by gmail](https://blog.google/products/gmail/making-email-safer-for-you-posted-by/), that incoming connections be TLS.  If the incoming connection is not TLS, gmail will display a warning about trusting the email...  There are plenty of other requirements along with domain reputation tracking elements... I highly discourage the use of the default settings for postfix or any other email server on an Internet facing machine...

Comment: It seems to me that "you cannot, because of *these* constraints" *is* an Answer.

Comment: @JeffSchaller if this is the real answer to the question as of 12/02/19, so be it...

Comment: @Christopher indeed I undetstood from your answer it's not possible; I meant to say: Either this question should be marked as duplicate or have an answer like Jeff mentioned.